# Trying to create a trigger that prevents updates based on value from another table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to prevent users from updating one table based on a date value from another table.

Table A contains rows that I would like to make un editable if a date value in the Table B is older than sysdate.

I need to somehow tell the trigger to check the row and use a foreign key in Table A's row to query its corresponding rows in Table B and then do this:

raise_application_error(-20000, 'It is too late to change this record');

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a homework assignment, you'd want something like this (I'm guessing at table structures and cardinalities since you don't specify).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  AFTER UPDATE ON a
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_dt_b b.dt_col%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT dt_col
    INTO l_dt_b
    FROM b
   WHERE b.b_key = :new.b_key;

  IF( l_dt_b < sysdate )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Too late' );
  END IF;
END;
```

If this is for a real system, however, trigger-based validation is problematic.  It is not safe in a multi-user system, for example.  In session 1, I may have modified the row in B but not yet committed the change.  You can then query the row in session 2, see the old value, and allow the `UPDATE`.  We can both commit our changes and nothing will detect that we have data in an invalid state.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I receive these errors when I test the trigger

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "[dbo].TRG_CHECK_DATE", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '[dbo].TRG_CHECK_DATE'

I also have to take the :new off of the :new.b_key as it tells me i am using a bad bind variable

Comment: @user2241161 - As I said, I'm guessing at cardinalities.  If `B` is the parent in the foreign key relationship, then the new row in `A` must point at exactly 1 row in `B`.  The error you are getting indicates that the query is returning more than one row.  That either means that you have not translated it to your data model correctly or that your data model doesn't actually have a proper foreign key relationship and there are multiple parent rows in `B` that relate to the new row in `A`.  `:new.b_key` refers to the `b_key` column in the new row you are inserting into the `A` table.

Comment: @user2241161 - If you are getting a "bad bind variable" error, that likely means that you specified the name of the column in `A` that references `B` incorrectly.  My guess was that the column would be named the same in both `A` and `B`.  It is possible that your data model is not that consistent.

Comment: In the end this was the code that worked

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_check_date
  AFTER UPDATE ON order_line
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_delivery_date placed_order.delivery_date%type;
  CURSOR c1 IS SELECT delivery_date
   INTO v_delivery_date 
    FROM placed_order
   WHERE placed_order.order_id = placed_order.order_id;
BEGIN
OPEN c1;
LOOP
  FETCH c1 INTO v_delivery_date;
EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c1;
  IF( v_delivery_date > (to_char(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')))
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'You cannot edit an order that is closed' );
  END IF;
END;

Thank You!

Comment: I have just read your comments, again thank you for sharing your knowledge!!

Comment: @user2241161 - You are reading every row from the `placed_order` table and basing the condition on whatever arbitrary row happens to be returned last.  It is extremely unlikely that this is correct.  If `delivery_date` is a date, it makes no sense to compare it to a string-- you're forcing Oracle to convert `sysdate` to a string and then back to a date again which will fail if your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` happens not to match the format mask you've specified.

Comment: I see, yes I tested it and that is absolutely correct. Table B is the parent table of a one to many relationship with table A. Table B has one order which has a number of order_lines which are in Table A. To make the trigger work do you suggest I fix the data model?

Comment: @user2241161 - Why don't you edit your question to include the actual table definitions you're working with (DDL statements), some sample data (DML statements), and some specific `UPDATE` statements that you want to succeed and some that you want to fail.  I'm guessing that your problem is translating my generic answer to your specific data model.  Since I don't know your specific data model, I'm going to struggle to help.